# iOS Swift Trouble Using HTML with Local File

Tags: html, ios, swift

To display a line of HTML code in a UIWebView, I used the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

let htmlString = "<html><body> Hello World! </body></html>"

myWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```

To display a ***formatted math equation*** in a UIWebView, I modified the above code to include a reference to the MathJax formatting engine in the HTML header (and added math equation to the body):

```
let htmlString = "<html><head><script src='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script></head><body> Hello World! $${ x^2 = 5 }$$ </body></html>"
```

If ***no internet connection***, I cannot access MathJax online.  Therefore, I instead add the MathJax files to my Xcode project and replace the "https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js" reference with the path to the locally-stored file.  For reference, the path turns out to be:

"/Users/RichardD/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A2CA12BC-5824-4DDA-AEBE-01FC9F0728F1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0B888EFA-FEEE-42C0-993D-1C51F73EFBD0/ThermodynamicsApp.app/MathJax-masterSlim/MathJax.js"

Code now looks like this:

```
//get path to locally-stored file:
let filePath: NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MathJax", ofType: "js", inDirectory: "MathJax-masterSlim")!

//merge path into HTML string:
let htmlString = "<html><head> <script src='" + (filePath as String) + "?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script> </head> <body> Hello World! $${ x^2 = 5 }$$  </body></html>"
```

HOWEVER, the above code results in text NOT formatted, which means either of two things:

1. I messed up the reference to the local files (perhaps syntax is wrong)
2. The reference is correct, but the local files aren't doing their job (for whatever reason).

***Would someone please comment on which of the above is the most likely issue?***
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you test it for yourself? See if you can write code to read that file.

Comment: jtbandes, I'm not sure I understand.  The "MathJax.js" file somehow processes the string (let's say my string is x^2) to give it formatting.  All I know how to do is to try to point the header to the local copy of the file instead of pointing it to the https internet located file.  What did you mean by "write code to read that file"?  Wait, I think I get you now. You're saying create at test file, then refer to it to see if the header reference is finding the file. Good point, I'll try that.

Comment: I meant that if you're concerned the local file is not accessible by the webview, you could try reading the file into memory to make sure that it's there. I would also recommend using the Safari Web Inspector to connect to the device/simulator and show it there are any JavaScript errors.

Comment: Thanks jtbandes.  I'll give it a shot.